# TikZ path with perpendicular and cycle doesn't connect nicely when rounded corners involved

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following MWE, the Ti*k*Z path with perpendicular and cycle doesn't connect nicely when rounded corners involved. Why, and how to circumvent the problem?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[rounded corners]
  (0,0) -- ++ (-.5,0) -- ++ (0,.5) -- ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (0,-4) -- ++ (8,0) |- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because Ti*k*Z thinks there will be two rounded corners at that point.

Comment: I don't know why but `rounded corners` do not play nicely with `-|` in different situations. You can check this "straight line" `\draw[rounded corners] (0,0) -| (2,0);`. Probably this has something to do with how `-|` are shortened, check this `\draw[shorten >= 3pt] (0,0) -| (2,0);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you add a rounded corners where there should not be one (<s>because of numerical minimal errors</s> I take that back, thanks to Kpym!), and here is how you can avoid that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[rounded corners]
  (0,0) -| ++ (-.5,.5) -- ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (0,-4) -- ++ (8,0)
  |- (1,0) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: As Kpym points out and is well known, such issues arise sometimes. Another way to rectify things in other situations is to just switch off rounded corners. I cannot apply this in a useful way here because the above is simpler, but I can show that this works.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[rounded corners]
  (0,0) -| ++ (-.5,.5) -- ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (0,-4) [rounded corners=false]
  -- ++ (8,0)  |- (1,0) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I understand that this is not what you are after here, but I found it useful in other situations to be able to temporarily switch off the rounded corners. In this regard, `rounded corners` are different from keys like `color` which you cannot change in this way along the path.

Comment: @Kpym Well, you can switch the corners of by adding `[rounded corners=false]`, e.g. `\draw[rounded corners]
  (0,0) -| ++ (-.5,.5) -- ++ (-2,0) -- ++ (0,-4) [rounded corners=false]
  -- ++ (8,0)  |- (1,0) -- cycle ;` in the situations you are referring to. You only have to add the key at the right moment. Here this is, however, not necessary.

Comment: @Kpym I know that they are not. Which is why I provide a way to overcome the problem. Could you perhaps let the OP decide what the question is?

Comment: @Kpym Honestly, I do not know what happens at the level of `pgfcorepathusage.code.tex` and even if I did I would not want to redefine anything done there. So far I could always circumvent the problem in the ways described above. I *thought* that these were rounding errors because there will be a tiny offset when the path gets closed (remember that `close path` does more than just connect to the starting point, it also adds a tiny arc or whatever is needed such that the result doesn't have a gap), but I cannot substantiate that. I still *think* this is a plausible explanation.

Comment: @Kpym Indeed, my question was not precise enough as I wanted both: why, and how to circumvent the problem? :) Now corrected.